# How to disable uefi variables

Tags: uefi, environment-variables

I need to disable uefi variables when booting from live usb. How do I do this?

I think that this is done through setting `noefi`, so if this is the right approach, how do I do this? I've tried from `grub-edit` like when temporarily setting `nomodeset`, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to disable EFI variables? There may be another way to accomplish your ultimate goal without messing with the EFI variables.

The `noefi` kernel option should indeed disable the EFI variables. If you've only tried it once, you might try it again; perhaps you mistyped it. I just tried on an Ubuntu 12.04 installation in VirtualBox, and `noefi` disabled the EFI variables support for me. (`efibootmgr` no longer worked and `/sys/firmware/efi` was missing.) You might also try placing it somewhere else amidst the kernel's options.

Another option is to boot using a BIOS-mode boot loader rather than an EFI-mode boot loader. If the USB device you're using is an Ubuntu installer, I believe it includes both types of boot loaders, so you should be able to use your firmware's boot option or possibly [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) 0.4.6 or later to select your boot mode. If you're using a custom USB flash drive, you'll need to install a BIOS version of GRUB manually.

A final option might be to remove the `efivars` kernel module, as in `rmmod efivars`, *after* booting. I tried to test this, but my test system uses a custom kernel with that module compiled in directly rather than as a module, so I can't guarantee that you'll be able to remove that module.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Disable it from GRUB via the `noefi` kernel option
2. or [make your firmware (BIOS) boot the USB in Legacy mode.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Setup_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode)
3. or use an ISO which is not EFI-compatible. Eg, Ubuntu32bit cannot boot in UEFI mode.